# Resource Wrapper for Dynamic Localization in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dynamic, localization

I achieved Dynamic Localization in Silverlight using the following blog post:
http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/06/21/dynamic-localization-in-silverlight.aspx

The solution works great. I can change my Language options and it works perfectly.

But as mentioned in the article i cannot get the design time support.
I designed a Resource Wrapper class for this:

```
 public sealed class ResourceWrapper  
    {
        //private static readonly ObservableResources<Resources> appResources = new ObservableResources<Resources>(resx);

        private  ObservableResources<Resources> appResources = new ObservableResources<Resources>(new Resources());
        public ObservableResources<Resources> ApplnResources
        {
            get { return appResources; }

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void UpdateBindings()
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ApplnResources"));
            }
        }

    }
```

In my app.xaml i added the ResourceWrapper class
In my Home.xaml i added the following lines of code:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper},Path=ApplnResources.LocalizationResources.CommentsEntry/>
```

By doing this i got my design time support back. But now when i run my application and change my Language it does not change?

can somebody help me with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your class ResourceWrapper should implement INotifyPropertyChanged event. Otherwise binding updating will not hook up.